# Animate MapView around screen

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have this animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{
            CGPoint centerLeft;
            centerLeft.x = self.leftMapPane.center.x - 100;
            centerLeft.y = self.leftMapPane.center.y;
            CGRect leftMove = CGRectMake(self.leftMapPane.frame.origin.x - 100, self.leftMapPane.frame.origin.x, self.leftMapPane.frame.size.width,     self.leftMapPane.frame.size.height);
            [self.leftMapPane setFrame:leftMove];
            [self.leftMapPane setCenter:centerLeft];
        }];
```

but for some reason although it gets inside the animation block, it doesn't move the mapViews I have around on the screen.
It should be noted that I'm not talking about moving the map but the view that contains the map, aka the mapview.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I created a simple project with a map view (leftMapPane) and copy+pasted your code and the animation worked fine.  So your animation call is fine, the problem must be in another part of your code.  Where are you calling the animation function from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation doesn't work in viewDidLoad because at that point the views have been loaded into memory but have not been necessarily added to the view hierarchy.  So when you try to animate the views it won't work.

Instead, put your animation call in viewDidAppear and it should work.  This way you're sure the views you're animating are in the view hierarchy.  I tried this in a sample project using your animation code and it worked fine.